# How can I map the Upload / attachment to a custom field of a custom object in surveys?

Tags: attachment, upload, fileupload, survey

I have below requirement. We are not getting upload/Attachment related questions while mirroring the questions to custom object fields. I am creating a survey. I have a survey questions which contains file attachment. when I use a option of mapping the file attachment to custom field to custom object i.e.. Mirroring the custom field with custom object, how can we map the upload related to custom field in custom object?

[image]

Comment: Could you have a ContentDocumentLink trigger that knows to associate a particular ContentDocument with both the Survey and your custom object? I'm familiar with writing a trigger like this but not so familiar with Surveys.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.